# Singular matrices over a commutative ring $R$, with a given adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

First, I apologize if this is a duplicate question.  I also must apologize if this has a trivial solution.

This question has two parts:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and let $F = R^n$ be a free module of finite rank.

1. Is it possible to construct a set of vectors $Z = \{v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}\}$ such that every subset of cardinality $n$ is a basis of $F$?
2. Does there exist $A\in Mat_{n+1}(R)$ such that $\det(A) = 0$, and
   $$\text{adj}(A) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
   \alpha_1 & \cdots & \cdots & \alpha_{n+1}\\
   0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
   \vdots & \ & \ & \vdots\\
   0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0
   \end{array}\right)$$
   where $\alpha_i \neq 0$, $\forall \ 1\leq i \leq n+1$?

---

1. I'm fairly certain this question is entirely trivial, as we could simply pick the standard basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ and then let $v = e_1 + \cdots + e_n$, and we claim that $Z = \{e_1,\ldots,e_n,v\}$ has the desired property.  In fact, this should work for any basis $X = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and setting $Z = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n,v\}$, where $v = x_1 + \cdots + x_n$, we claim $Z$ has the desired property.  (Does this work?)
2. This is a bit less clear.  My initial instinct is that the answer is no, but I have not yet been able to show it.

---

Full disclosure: This is not for homework, but is related to an issue that came up in thinking through a problem for a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you can answer (1) but not (2). With your example in (1), consider
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&v_1^T\\ 0&v_2^T\\ \vdots&\vdots\\ 0&v_{n+1}^T
\end{bmatrix}
=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{array}{c}0\\ \vdots\\ 0\end{array} & \Large I_n\\
\hline
0 & \begin{array}{ccc}1&\cdots&1\end{array}\\
\end{array}
\right].
$$

Comment: This was the example I thought of initially, but I couldn't convince myself that it was actually this simple.  Apparently I'm overthinking it, so I'll take another look at this in the morning.  Thanks.

Comment: I see my mistake now.  I made a small error when computing the adjoint of that matrix the first time, so I of course wasn't reaching the correct conclusion.  Thanks!